# Excel macro column splitting

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for help on a macro to take chunks of data on further rows, and place them into columns instead.

I've attached a picture to depict this. All of the chunks of data will split determined by the first column, 1 or 2 in the picture. I simply want to move chunk two up and next to 1. The only problem I've run into is that for each chunk, the number of columns is variable.

Edit: Image link incase the embedded isn't showing up: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUtww.png)

[image]

Would this be relatively close?

```
Sub macro() 
Dim wav_name As String 

Range("A1").Select 

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "" 
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select 
wav_name = ActiveCell.Value 
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 

Do 
    If ActiveCell.Value = wav_name Then 
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
    Else 
        Exit Do 
    End If 
Loop 

Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select 
Selection.Cut 
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste 

Loop 

Range("A1").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason your image isn't showing up for me, so I'm not sure I follow the logic, but it's worth noting that you don't need to select cells in order to work with them.

Comment: There needs to be some kind of specification as to when and where the 1 and 2 stuff will be, just seems mostly random right now.  Could some of the random stuff be 1 and 2s also?

Comment: The 1 and 2 will be in the first column. All other columns of data will be arbitrary data, we just want to split it when that first column changes, and move that chunk up and next to it's predecessor.

Comment: Do you only have two chunks to re-order, or multiple chunks to move on the same sheet?

Comment: Multiple, actually I should say a LOT. It's research data. I just tried fiddling with what I've set as the answer below but it's not working quite right. It is simply shifting everything over FAR to like, XEW column..

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is pretty workable with a one key exception.

Your cut selection is only grabbing the first row of data. You will need to change it to

```
Range(ActiveCell).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

To handle the variable number of columns, you can capture the last column in section one by adding a varabile (i.e. LastCol) and putting the following code in your Do Loop

```
LastCol = Activecell.End(xlToRight).Column
```

Then replace the 3 in your last offset statement with your variable

Note that you can refactor the code to remove many of the select statements (includeing the ones I have mentioned above) if you need to improve the preformance of your code, but what you have  written will work for you.

EDIT: Here is what your end code would look like

```
Sub macro() 
Dim wav_name As String 
Dim LastCol as Long

Range("A1").Select 

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "" 
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select 
wav_name = ActiveCell.Value 
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
LastCol = Activecell.End(xlToRight).Column

Do 
    If ActiveCell.Value = wav_name Then 
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
    Else 
        Exit Do 
    End If 
Loop 

Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Selection.Cut 
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(0, LastCol +1).Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste 

Loop 

Range("A1").Select 
End Sub
```

I haven't tested this, so you may have to do some debugging... but it is now logically correct.

Comment: Performance is no issue. However I'm not 100% where you're sticking and replacing code with the above, mind illustrating?

Comment: Hey Pynner, think we could work on this? As it stands, it isn't working correctly. Right now it's simply shifting everything wayyyy over to the right, to column XEW. It isn't seperating the data based on column A at all. Also, it throws an error on "ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(0, LastCol + 1).Select" stating application-defined or object-defined error (error 1004)